# UIAlert View on CustomCell Button Click

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a working customCell with tableView.I want to show a UIAlertView on button click.I have a method that responds to button click.How can i show the alert view with that method?

Method i am using is in the

### tavleView.m:

```
 -(void) btnAction:(id) sender
  {
    NSLog(@"i am here");    
  }
```

and the Cell event response as :

```
 [cell.ansBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Can anyone tell me how can i show the alertView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"your message title" message:@"some message" delegate:@"self/you may give the instance of other class" cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert relase];
```

Comment: ok..it's done...thanks...tell me something...how can i show the UIbutton title/id/text on the alertView?

Comment: you should write  message:buttonobject.titlelable.text instead of message:@"some message"